# Call Bootstrap Modal partially does not appear on production

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

In my application, I have a button which when clicked, it will show a bootstrap modal.

Index.cshtml

```
<button id="btnModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="modal-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnModal").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/TestModal/",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        $("#modal-container").html(data);
                        $("#myModal").modal(show = true, backdrop = false);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(error);
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

_TestModal.cshtml

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above code, I place content of modal in a PartialView, then I'm using jquery ajax to call modal. In the HomeController I've just return PartialView

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult TestModal()
{
    return PartialView("_TestModal");
}
```

I see in developer tools, there is an error when I clicked Lauch demo modal button

```
GET http://xxx/Home/TestModal/?_=1400038826500 404 (Not Found)
```

I placed Index.cshtml and _TestModal.cshtml in the same folder. If I run in my local development, the modal is appeared. Could you help me what wrong with the code?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with MVC 5.1 and Windows 7 for development.
Production server using windows server 2008 and IIS 6.

Comment: Ok this is a long shot as i dont have time to replicate all your code. but i think you just might need to remove the final / on the action call inthe ajax. url: "/Home/TestModal/", to url: "/Home/TestModal",

Comment: @KevDevMan good catch, but is there any explanation, why it is failed on production?

Comment: usually when i see an issue where it works in dev and not in production i would check the following - Server settings, Make sure IIS (if you are using it) has the same features enabled (add remove programs - add windows features). Make sure you have included all your JS and CSS files in the build (and make sure there are none left on the production server). This sounds like an IIS issue to me.